# Laravel clean way to handle data after a webhook

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

So I got webhooks working and I also got a source polling page where ajax checks the status of the payment.

But now I don't know how to handle the data in a clean way.
I could post the data from a view to a controller but I don't like it that way.
I could also change the webhooks to return to a route, but I don't know if that will mess stripe up, since it wont get a http 200 (ok) status.

So what is a clean way to deal with a customer after he paid? Where should I redirect him to and how can I make sure my controller gets the user data after he paid.

Comment: just handle the webhook data and don't render or process anything on a different routes you should only update the payment status and call other functions that handle the subscription/purchase. You should look into other open source e-commerce solutions such as open cart about the purchase flow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got to agree that this looks like a proper way to do it, but I also want to let customers know the payment was a succes and let them download a pdf after payment has been processed. So I would have to include the data in the pdf. But I could also lead them to their control panel, which should be ready by the time they get there.

Comment: You could listen for the webhook response on a controller.  Which will create a Laravel [Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications).  That way the client gets a message right after the webhook has completed.  You should be able to receive invoice number and other details that are useful as well as provide them with a unique url for the PDF.  The notification can be done in the App, via email or SMS.